# how to sort the data before applying terms aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-8

we want to sort the data using few fileds before applying terms aggregation, tried using terms and sort sub aggregation using which sort is working however terms aggregation is giving duplicate records.

elastic search version: 8.7.1

**sample elatic search doc :**

```
{
  "itemDetails": {
    "itemId": "3076",
    "itemId2": "1003918865",
    "usecase": "habc",
    "usecaseId": "xyz"
  },
  "metaData": {
    "cId": "96ff54507c2d018e5c767785c705a5b2",
    "date1": "2023-09-29T12:29:54",
    "date2": "2023-09-29T12:30:09"
  }
other properties....
}
```

In the above doc first i would like to sort the records using date1 and date2 then need to get the distinct records using "cId".

using below query able to sort the data based on date1 and date2 however we are getting records with duplicate cId:

**Query1:**

```
POST /index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.itemId": [
              "3076"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.usecase": [
              "habc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "metaData.date1": {
              "lte": "2023-09-30T19:55:54.611Z",
              "gte": "2023-09-27T19:55:54.611Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sortby_date1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metaData.date1",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 6
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sortby_date2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "metaData.date2",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "groupby_cId": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "metaData.cId"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "top_doc": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "includes": [
                        "itemDetails.itemId",
                        "itemDetails.usecase",
                        "metaData.cId",
                        "metaData.date1"
                      
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query2** : Terms aggregation not giving unique records when used with sort.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.itemId": [
              "3077"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.usecase": [
              "xyz"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "metaData.date1": {
              "lte": "2023-09-30T19:55:54.611Z",
              "gte": "2023-09-27T19:55:54.611Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "metaData.date1": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "metaData.date2": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_cIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metaData.cId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                        "itemDetails.itemId",
                        "itemDetails.usecase",
                        "metaData.cId",
                        "metaData.date1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**current response using the query mentioned in the answer:**

```
{"aggregations": {
    "sterms#distinct_cIds": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "96ff54507c2d01",
          "doc_count": 101,
          "top_hits#top_doc": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 101,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "index",
                  "_id": "BN0vhoAyg",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "itemId": "3077",
                      "usecase": "xyz"
                    },
                    "metaData": {
                      "cId": "96ff54507c2d01",
                      "date1": "2023-09-29T12:29:54",
                      "date2": "2023-09-29T13:30:57"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1695990594000,
                    1695994257000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "846bc8708b746b23674",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_hits#top_doc": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "index",
                  "_id": "BN0vhoAyg1",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "itemId": "3077",
                      "usecase": "xyz"
                    },
                    "metaData": {
                      "cId": "846bc8708b746b23674",
                      "date1": "2023-09-29T03:34:08",
                      "date2": "2023-09-29T13:30:57"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1695990594000,
                    1695994257000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "27053a17a1919f",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_hits#top_doc": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "index",
                  "_id": "BN0vhoAyg1",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "itemId": "3077",
                      "usecase": "xyz"
                    },
                    "metaData": {
                      "cId": "27053a17a1919f",
                      "date1": "2023-09-27T21:58:33",
                      "date2": "2023-09-27T21:58:34"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1695990594000,
                    1695994257000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "74dc2fff7f4b5635b",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_hits#top_doc": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "index",
                  "_id": "BN0vhoAyg1",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "itemDetails": {
                      "itemId": "3077",
                      "usecase": "xyz"
                    },
                    "metaData": {
                      "cId": "74dc2fff7f4b5635b",
                      "date1": "2023-09-29T23:36:38",
                      "date2": "2023-09-29T23:36:41",
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1695990594000,
                    1695994257000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
```

**Expected Response**

```
now we are getting latest records using date1 and date2 in case of duplicates, we would also need latest record among unique cIds based on date1 and date2, record with "cId": "74dc2fff7f4b5635b" should come at the top as it contains latest date1 and date2 compare to other cIds.
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're using a terms aggregation for date fields with second precision?

Comment: Hi @Val, Thankyou for your response , we are using terms aggregation for "cId"  to get unique records, before getting unique records we need to sort the data based on date1 and date2 to get the latest unique records, used Query2 as updated in the question: when we use sort and terms together sort is working but terms not giving unique records. could you help

Comment: The top level sort is only applied to hits, and has no effect on the aggregations. When you set size to 0 because you're only interested in aggregation results (i.e. unique cId), top-level sort is of no value to you. What do date1 and date2 represent? start and end time of the event? Do you need the top-1 cId for each date1/date2 pairs?

Comment: Do you need the top-1 cId for each date1/date2 pairs--yes @Val. 
date1 and date2 represent? start and end time of the event?--yes similar to that, we need to sort with date1 and date2 to get latest record.

Comment: ok, then I don't understand why you say that some cId are duplicated? how is that possible since each cId can only have a single date1 and a single date2, they can only fall within a single bucket

Comment: Hi @Val, here cId is duplicate becuase date1 and date2 indicates when event has occurred , we will have multiple event for same cId and need to get the latest event

Comment: ok, so we can aggregate by cId and then only return the latest one sorted by date1, that should work right?

Comment: Hi @Val, how to remove duplicates, we need to remove duplicates after sorting to get the latest record, sort should be performed using both date1 and date2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You should simply aggregate by `cId` to get a unique record for each and then return the top hit sorted by descending `date1` and `date2`.

Note that the top level sort is only applied to hits, and has no effect on the aggregations. When you set size to 0 because you're only interested in aggregation results (i.e. unique cId), the top-level sort is of no value to you, but you can add it to the `top_hits` aggregation:

```
POST /index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.itemId": [
              "3076"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.usecase": [
              "habc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "metaData.date1": {
              "lte": "2023-09-30T19:55:54.611Z",
              "gte": "2023-09-27T19:55:54.611Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_cIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metaData.cId"
        "order": { "max_date1": "desc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date1": { 
          "max": { "field": "metaData.date1" } 
        },
        "top_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
               {"metaData.date1": "desc"},           <---- add this sort
               {"metaData.date2": "desc"}            <---- add this sort
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                        "itemDetails.itemId",
                        "itemDetails.usecase",
                        "metaData.cId",
                        "metaData.date1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample response you get? I'm pretty sure there's a misunderstanding

Comment: Hi @Val, pls ignore my previous reply, above query is giving unique and latest records for given cId. but we also need to sort the records with cId having latest date1 and date2 . attaching the sample response in the above answer

Comment: Ok, we can sort the cId by date, but only one of them not two. I've updated my answer please have a look

Comment: Hi @Val, have updated the expected results in the above answer, can you pls have a look and please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: Please update your question not my answer

Comment: Hi @Val, have update the question with my query, please let me know if you have inputs

Comment: The response you have shown in your answer is not the response to my query because I don't see any `max_date1` aggregation. Please try again

Comment: Hi @Val, thanks for the reply, it is response to the query in the answer, we have around 100 records for cId: 96ff54507c2d01 with different date1 and date2 after using your query am getting latest record for 96ff54507c2d01 with max date1 and date2 as expected, however we also need sort the records with different cIds in the above response using date1 and date2

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest query in my answer? There should be a `max_date1` aggregation which I don't see in your answer. Please double check again

Comment: Hi @Val, sorry haven’t noticed that change, it is working!! thankyou somuch, one last query is if we specify multiple itemDetails.itemId in the query, how can we limit the results to return only 5 records for each itemDetails.itemId in the above response.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked out! If you don't mind, you should create a new thread for your additional question as it's a different issue. Thank you

Comment: sure @Val, Thankyou!!

Comment: Hi @Val, have posted a question for above query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300393/how-to-limit-the-response-size-in-terms-aggregation-in-elastic-search, pls let me know if you have any inputs