# how to limit the response size in terms aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-8

Am using below elastic search query and getting the response, but how to limit the response size of each itemDetails.itemId specified in the query.

elastic search version: 8.7.1

**sample elatic search doc :**

```
{
  "itemDetails": {
    "itemId": "3076",
    "usecase": "habc",
    "usecaseId": "xyz"
  },
  "metaData": {
    "cId": "96ff54507c2d018e5c767785c705a5b2",
    "date1": "2023-09-29T12:29:54",
    "date2": "2023-09-29T12:30:09"
  }
other properties....
}
```

**input query :**

```
POST /index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.itemId": [
              "3076",
              "1111",
              "2222"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.usecase": [
              "habc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "metaData.date1": {
              "lte": "2023-09-30T19:55:54.611Z",
              "gte": "2023-09-27T19:55:54.611Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_cIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metaData.cId"
        "order": { "max_date1": "desc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date1": { 
          "max": { "field": "metaData.date1" } 
        },
        "top_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
               {"metaData.date1": "desc"},          
               {"metaData.date2": "desc"}          
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                        "itemDetails.itemId",
                        "itemDetails.usecase",
                        "metaData.cId",
                        "metaData.date1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**expected result:if size is 2, response should contain 2 records for each itemDetails.itemId**

**Reference question :** : [this query is continuation of reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287368/how-to-sort-the-data-before-applying-terms-aggregation-in-elastic-search/77288099?noredirect=1#comment136275474_77288099)

**Attaching the response for query mentioned in the answer below:**

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "f8d79b2856e894c9e88852f65120e9e3",
    "doc_count": 1,
    "sterms#distinct_itemId": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "3076",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_hits#top_doc": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "max#max_date1": {
            "value": 1697385179000,
            "value_as_string": "2023-10-15T15:52:59.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "153c067041341dc4d2052313d3f0891f",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sterms#distinct_itemId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "3076",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "top_hits#top_doc": {
                  "hits": {
                    "total": {
                      "value": 1,
                      "relation": "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score": null,
                    "hits": [
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "max#max_date1": {
            "value": 1697303179000,
            "value_as_string": "2023-10-14T17:06:19.000Z"
          }
        }
...still continues, i think it is giving all response to distinct crawlIds
```

Comment: Which `size` do you refer to? the top-level one or the one in the top_hits aggregation?

Comment: Hi @Val, thanks for your response, have set top level size to 0 as am not interested in the search results, size am interested is aggregations response size, may be top_hits aggregation size

Comment: So if the top hits size is 2, you will only get two hits, not two hits per itemId. Do you want to get two hits per itemId within each cId?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two results per `itemId`, you need to add another `terms` sub-aggregation for the `itemDetails.itemId` field, as shown below:

```
POST /index/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.itemId": [
              "3076",
              "1111",
              "2222"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "itemDetails.usecase": [
              "habc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "metaData.date1": {
              "lte": "2023-09-30T19:55:54.611Z",
              "gte": "2023-09-27T19:55:54.611Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_cIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metaData.cId",
        "order": {
          "max_date1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date1": {
          "max": {
            "field": "metaData.date1"
          }
        },
        "distinct_itemId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "itemDetails.itemId"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_doc": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 2,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "metaData.date1": "desc"
                  },
                  {
                    "metaData.date2": "desc"
                  }
                ],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "itemDetails.itemId",
                    "itemDetails.usecase",
                    "metaData.cId",
                    "metaData.date1"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val, above query is giving multiple records to same itemId, have attached response for above query in the question, can you please check

Comment: You're not executing the query I gave you because `top_doc` should be nested inside `distinct_itemId` and that's not what you're response shows

Comment: Hi @Val, have corrected query, now also getting multiple records for same itemId, have updated response in my question , please check